# JSON stored in a cookie returns un-decodable

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

My wordpress site is storing some useful JSON in a cookie.  When I retrieve it and decode it, it returns NULL.  I have looked at other posts that seem to think it's a UTF-8 issue.  I don't think I can change that because of wordpress.  Is there a better way to solve this than string replacing the extra quotes/backslashes/etc?

```
 $ckData = array("initialTime" => $initialTime,"cpCode" => $cpData[0], "cpID" =>cpData[1],"cpExpiry" => $cpExpiry);
 $ckDataJSON = json_encode($ckData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
setcookie( '_thecookie', $ckDataJSON, $ckExpiry, '/', 'mysitexyz.com', true, false);
```

it returns this from the cookie:
string(68) "{\"initialTime\":1524240724,\"cpCode\":null,\"cpExpiry\":1524241624}"

which when passed through json_decode returns NULL

Comment: How do you encode it and put it in the cookie? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: you can show the code how save json on session please !!

Comment: @AbraCadaver added the info you asked about

Comment: `echo get_magic_quotes_gpc();` If on then disable it, or just use `stripslashes` as stated.

Comment: @AbraCadaver once i used stripslashes, it decoded just fine.  add as an answer and I'll choose it!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your server appears to be running an old version of PHP prior to 5.4.0 with [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php#security.magicquotes) enabled, you should upgrade.

You need to strip the slashes for valid JSON:

```
$result = json_decode(stripslashes($cookie));
```